# Migrating whisper database from one graphite to another graphite

Tags: graphite, collectd

How can we migrate  whisper database files from one graphite to another graphite node using whisper merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [carbonate](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbonate/) or [Bucky tools](https://github.com/jjneely/buckytools) .

Comment: Thanks, I was planning to use whisper merge utility.
Do you know how we can use it ?

Comment: run ./whisper-merge --help, it is self-explanatory.